# Copy whole project into git

Tags: xcode, git

I have installed git on my PC and made a repository. How can I copy my whole xcode project into git? Can I copy the files manually into the branches folder?

Comment: Do this | http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy your files over to that directory, and then do the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Or... just make your repository within your project that you already have, with `git init`.